# Is there a site to upload text files?

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-mate, pastebin

I would like to upload text files to a site so I can share with others.

The sites that I use only allow pictures.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `pastebinit`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit

pastebinit can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo apt install pastebinit
```

It's frequently used in bug reporting, IRC & other docs for sharing text files.

Copying from the link I provided:

> Once you have pastebinit installed it's time to test it out.
>
> The command for pastebinit in the terminal is:
>
> `<command> | pastebinit`
>
> For example if you were having grub issues and someone in the IRC ask you to post your menu.lst into a pastebin you would enter the following in a terminal:
>
> `cat /boot/grub/menu.lst | pastebinit`

Comment: The example command for Grub (`menu.lst` was grub version 1) shows how long `pastebinit` has been doing this..  When someone starts pasting many lines of output on IRC; a *bot* will silence them (automatically) and users can `!pastebinit` to show instructions on using `pastebinit`....